# UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UITableViewCell - double call

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using the UILongPressGestureRecognizer in a cell. 
What I need is: when a user taps a cell for 1.0 seconds, call one view controller.
If the user taps the cell, another VC.

I can accomplish that by using the UILongPressGestureRecognizer. But the issue is that is calls the viewController twice.

Code:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1){
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(memberListWithSearchOptions)];

    longPressTap.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;

    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressTap];
    [longPressTap release];
}
```

I think that what I need is, after recognizing the LongPress, disable the recognizer, until the tableView appears again on screen.

How can I do that?

Thanks,

RL

Comment: The gesture interpreted by a gesture recognizer can be either *discrete* or *continuous*. Continuous gesture recognizers such as `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` trigger their action methods multiple times.You can check if the `state` property of the gesture recognizer is set to `UIGestureRecognizerBegan` if you want to do some logic as soon as the gesture begins or `UIGestureRecognizerEnded` to do some logic when the gesture is done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of disabling it, what you probably need to do is check the gesture recognizer's `state` property and only display the next view controller if the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` (or `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`).

You'll need to change your method to accept the gesture recognizer as a parameter (and also update the `@selector` parameter) and check it's state:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressTap = 
    [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
        action:@selector(memberListWithSearchOptions:)];  //colon at end

//...

- (void)memberListWithSearchOptions:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)lpt
{
    if (lpt.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        //or check for UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded instead
    {
        //display view controller...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to check state as below

```
-  (void)memberListWithSearchOptions:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
    //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
}
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");
    //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
}
```