# UIActionSheet called twice?

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

My app simply calls one UIActionSheet like this:

```
UIActionSheet *dataCopySheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy Element     Information" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Name", @"Melting Point", @"Boiling Point", @"Atomic Mass", @"Density", @"Discovery Info", @"Save Image", nil];
[dataCopySheet showInView:detailView];
```

For some reason, two UIActionSheets are shown from this (one comes up over the other). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You must be calling this code twice. Put a breakpoint at the code above and run the app. Look at the stack trace each time the breakpoint is reached to determine who is calling and why it's being called twice.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It's only called once but still, two come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out... I called the action sheet from a UILongPressGestureRecognizer, and it was called twice. I changed it to a UITapGestureRecognizer and now it's only called once, works great. Odd issue with UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Comment: With the long press gesture recognizer, you need to check its `state`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907671/ios-uiactionsheet-presented-from-longpress-gesture-on-a-button-erroneously-requi.