# UIAlertView getting called Twice in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uialertview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UITableViewCell - double call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688329/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-on-uitableviewcell-double-call)

I am new to iPhone,

I am displaying Alert when Button is pressed long, but when i press button long my alert view  gets called again.

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (IBAction)longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    //Gets text of Button.
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[gestureRecognizer view];
    BtnText= [btn titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"longPressDetected");

    UIAlertView* alert_view = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle: @"Are you sure want to Delete ?" message:nil delegate: self 
                               cancelButtonTitle: @"Yes" otherButtonTitles: @"No", nil];
    [alert_view show];
    [alert_view release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
    if (buttonIndex==0) {

        [self ReloadView];
         [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];
    }
    else{
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:TRUE];
    }
}
```

**Any help will be appreciated.**

**EDIT:**

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
         for(int i=0;i<10i++)
            {

                if(i!=0)
                {
                    if (i%4==0) 
                    {                    
                        ypos+=180;
                        xpos=30;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xpos+=200;
                    }
                }


                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                button.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 120,130);
                [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ibook2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Downloadedepubs objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                 LongPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
                [LongPress addTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
                 LongPress.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
                [button addGestureRecognizer:LongPress];
                [self.view addSubview:button];
                [LongPress release];

      } 

   }
```

Comment: How many times is - (IBAction)longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer getting called? Can you put break point or NSLog and check?

Comment: When it is called twice then you may have added the gesture recogniser twice.

Comment: @krunal ... vikram is right ... check that how many times this longPressDetected is getting called :D

Comment: I kept NSLog inside longPressDetected it gets called twice.`longPressDetected` is delegate method why it is getting called twice ?

Comment: i posted new answer .. please check it,,,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is a long event process. Please check the event state either it has started, completed etc.

```
- (IBAction)longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {        

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

        NSLog(@"Long press began");

    } else if ( gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized ) {

            NSLog(@"Long press UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized");
    }
    else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        NSLog(@"Long press Ended");
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"Long press detected.");
    }       
}
```

I think, better to use the **UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan** state in your case.

Please modify your `longPressDetected()` as

```
 -(IBAction)longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

   if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

       UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[gestureRecognizer view];
       BtnText= [btn titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
       NSLog(@"longPressDetected");

      UIAlertView* alert_view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Are you sure want to Delete ?" message:nil delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Yes" otherButtonTitles: @"No", nil];
      [alert_view show];
      [alert_view release];
      alert_view = nil;

   }
 }
```

Please check all the below **UIGestureRecognizerStates**

```
    UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible,   // the recognizer has not yet recognized its gesture, but may be evaluating touch events. this is the default state

    UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan,      // the recognizer has received touches recognized as the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop
    UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged,    // the recognizer has received touches recognized as a change to the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop
    UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded,      // the recognizer has received touches recognized as the end of the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop and the recognizer will be reset to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible
    UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled,  // the recognizer has received touches resulting in the cancellation of the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop. the recognizer will be reset to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible

    UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed,     // the recognizer has received a touch sequence that can not be recognized as the gesture. the action method will not be called and the recognizer will be reset to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible

    // Discrete Gestures – gesture recognizers that recognize a discrete event but do not report changes (for example, a tap) do not transition through the Began and Changed states and can not fail or be cancelled
    UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded // the recognizer has received touches recognized as the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop and the recognizer will be reset to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible
```

Comment: Amazing answer, it's working. is it good ? if i write this `if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)` instead of `if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple to solve this even without the need to enter in UILongPressGestureRecognizer details. Define a `BOOL isShowingAlertView`. When you call `[alertView show]`, you set `isShowingAlertView = YES`, and when you dismiss it, `isShowingAlertView = NO`. And before calling, you just check: `if (isShowingAlertView == NO)` and only then you show it:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    isShowingAlert = NO;
}

- (IBAction)longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if (isShowingAlert == NO)
    {
        isShowingAlert = YES;
        //Gets text of Button.
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[gestureRecognizer view];
        BtnText= [btn titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"longPressDetected");

        UIAlertView* alert_view = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle: @"Are you sure want to Delete ?" message:nil delegate: self 
                               cancelButtonTitle: @"Yes" otherButtonTitles: @"No", nil];
        [alert_view show];
        [alert_view release];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    isShowingAlert = NO;
    if (buttonIndex==0)
    {
        [self ReloadView];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: tried but still getting called twice.

Comment: when i press `Yes` or `No` button for first time alert view gets dismiss with animation, because i wrote `animated:TRUE` but still one more alert view is there in the background.

Comment: @Krunal what are you writing when you are adding this longPressDetected in your code ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you dismiss it animated or not (and we usually put YES or NO instead of TRUE or FALSE). Did you declare `BOOL isShowingAlert` in the interface file? I use this in a lot of apps and all work.

Comment: @krunal ...why are you writing this [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE]; ... you want to refresh when you press 0 right? then do just that

Comment: Ya i want to refresh a whole view when alert view `Yes` button is clicked.

Comment: write  [LongPress release]; in dealloc and check ... I dont know this may work or may not .. but you should always write release in dealloc if you have declared instance variable of that

Comment: i have posted a new answer.. please check it